# React Native - focus on react-native-paper TextInput

Tags: react-native, jsx, react-native-paper

In my react native application, I created a screen with two input text from react-native-paper. How to make the second input receive focus when the screen is loaded and its content (2) is selected?

Follow the code below:

```
import { 
    StyleSheet,
    View,
} from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {

  return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <TextInput
          value={1}
        />
        <TextInput
          ref={this.nomeInputRef}
          value={2}
        />
      </View>
  );


}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
});
```

The code is available at https://snack.expo.dev/VhnUa5XqC

Thanks!!

Comment: why do not using TextInput of react-native?

Comment: I use react-native-paper specific styles and also use masks in conjunction with TextInputMask